# Variável retorna NULL - Trying to get property of non-object laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

Alguém me ajuda estou com esse erro
Variável retorna NULL - Trying to get property of non-object

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seu exemplo poderia estar escrito pra facilitar a vida de quem está visitando o site para consultar a pergunta e pra te responder também. Dá uma lida nessas regrinhas aqui: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-completo-e-verific%c3%a1vel?cb=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a exception, no instante em que você tenta pegar a propriedade `$user->id`, a variável `$user` não é um objeto. Na verdade, essa variável é nula.

Isso porque você está atribuindo à variável `$user` o retorno da função `attach`, [que é do tipo void](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/InteractsWithPivotTable.html#method_attach):

```php
$user = (...)->attach($permissao->id);
```

Para corrigir o problema, é só fragmentar o seu código em duas partes:

```php
$user = User::create([
    'nome' => $request->nome,
    'email' => $request->email,
    'password' => bcrypt($request->password)
]);

$user->roles()->attach($permissao->id);

// Continua o código normalmente...
```

Comment: perfeito, deu certinho.... muito obrigado